# how should I implement data access/rights management in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I am making a SaaS application in which users will create advertisement listings.

1. All advertisements should be visible to all users of my registered users as well as unregistered visitors
2. Only registered users can create an advertisement
3. A registered user can create several advertisements
4. Only the user who creates the advertisement should be able to delete or edit it.

I have never done user and data management w.r.t. a database so I need advice on how I should implement it (I acknowledge that this is an open question but I still feel it is relevant as where else could I ask!!)

My database is `cassandra`.

- I am thinking of using a single keyspace for all the advertisements
  to address point#1
- I am thinking of creating a dedicate keyspace for
  each user where their advertisements will be stored (point#2, point#3
  and point#4).
- If a use edits/deletes an advertisement then the
  user-specific keyspace and the global keyspace for all advertisements
  would need to be changed

Question 1 - Is my approach the usual way of creating such an application? If not, I'll appreciate suggestions on alternate designs.

Question 2 - As I'll create user specific keyspaces, would I be able to programatically create a keyspace (with user's provided username and password) as part of my web signup process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not good idea to have per user keyspace in Cassandra, this will work only if you have a couple of users. The individual keyspaces will mean that you're creating a separate tables for every user, so it will contradict the point 1 - to show all advertisements you'll need to read from all of tables. And Cassandra also has limitations on number of tables that it can support - recommended values are not more 500 tables in cluster (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324790/how-many-max-number-of-tables-i-can-create-in-a-given-cassandra-cluster-is-the/57325558#57325558) for more details).

I recommend just to put user ID as a part of the partition key, or partition key itself - but this will depend on the other factors, like, how many advertisements can user create, etc. - this requires a separate question.

I suggest to take DS220 course on Cassandra data modelling at [DataStax Academy](https://academy.datastax.com/) just to get better understanding how to model data for Cassandra.