# How to create an update statement where a UDT value need to be updated using QueryBuilder

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I have the following `udt type`

```
CREATE TYPE tag_partitions(
  year bigint,
  month bigint);
```

and the following table

```
CREATE TABLE ${tableName} (
  tag text,
  partition_info set<FROZEN<tag_partitions>>,
  PRIMARY KEY ((tag))
)
```

The table schema is mapped using the following model

```scala
case class TagPartitionsInfo(year:Long, month:Long)
case class TagPartitions(tag:String, partition_info:Set[TagPartitionsInfo])
```

I have written a function which should create an `Update.IfExists` query: But I don't know how I should update the `udt` value. I tried to use `set` but it isn't working.

```scala
def updateValues(tableName:String, model:TagPartitions, id:TagPartitionKeys):Update.IfExists = {
   val partitionInfoType:UserType = session.getCluster().getMetadata
       .getKeyspace("codingjedi").getUserType("tag_partitions")
   //create value
   //the logic below assumes that there is only one element in the set
   val partitionsInfoSet:Set[UDTValue] = model.partition_info.map((partitionInfo:TagPartitionsInfo) =>{
      partitionInfoType.newValue()
        .setLong("year",partitionInfo.year)
        .setLong("month",partitionInfo.month)
   })
   println("partition info converted to UDTValue: "+partitionsInfoSet)

   QueryBuilder.update(tableName).
      `with`(QueryBuilder.WHAT_TO_DO_HERE_TO_UPDATE_UDT("partition_info",partitionsInfoSet))
      .where(QueryBuilder.eq("tag", id.tag)).ifExists()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was I was adding `partitionsInfoSet` in the table but it is a Set of Scala. I needed to convert into Set of Java using `setAsJavaSet`

```
    QueryBuilder.update(tableName).`with`(QueryBuilder.set("partition_info",setAsJavaSet(partitionsInfoSet)))
      .where(QueryBuilder.eq("tag", id.tag))
      .ifExists()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, it didn't answer your exact question, wouldn't it be easier to use [Object Mapper](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/object_mapper/) for this? Something like this (I didn't modify it heavily to match your code):

```scala
@UDT(name = "scala_udt")
case class UdtCaseClass(id: Integer, @(Field @field)(name = "t") text: String) {
  def this() {
    this(0, "")
  }
}

@Table(name = "scala_test_udt")
case class TableObjectCaseClassWithUDT(@(PartitionKey @field) id: Integer,
                                       udts: java.util.Set[UdtCaseClass]) {
  def this() {
    this(0, new java.util.HashSet[UdtCaseClass]())
  }
}
```

and then just create case class and use `mapper.save` on it. (Also note that you need to use Java collections, until you're imported Scala codecs).

The primary reason for using Object Mapper could be ease of use, and also better performance, because it's using prepared statements under the hood, instead of built statements that are much less efficient.

You can find more information about Object Mapper + Scala in [article that I wrote recently](https://academy.datastax.com/content/using-object-mapper-scala).

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'll try this approach.

Comment: Alex - Could you please look at this one as well?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285428/how-should-i-implement-data-access-rights-management-in-cassandra